# Are there two different things called clearfix?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I'm a bit confused regarding what a clearfix really is. On one hand we have the situation with zero height divs where a floated element doesn't take up space. The solution is to put the following clearfix class on the container:

```
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

On the other hand we have a clearfix which seems to be used to get rid of the need to put a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` when you don't want the next element to float. This hack is usually much more elaborate like the following from HTML5Boilerplate:

```
.clearfix:after { 
  content: "."; 
  display: block; 
  height: 0; 
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.clearfix { 
  display: inline-block;  
}
* html .clearfix {  
  height: 1%;  
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clearfix {  
  display: block;  
}
```

Why are these concepts called the same thing? I'm not talking about different solutions to the same problem but two different problems completely (fixing zero-height divs versus eliminating the need of a clear: both div).

Comment: There can be different implementations. But the idea is the same anyway.

Comment: I was wondering about `Hides from IE-mac`, IE on Mac ? :P

Comment: _“An Audi and a BMW look different – so how come they are both called a car?”_

Comment: @dfsq but how is it the same idea when they are tackling two completely different problems?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is two different approaches to make a "clearfix".

The more straight forward approach is to simply add another element that uses the `clear` style. Here shown with inline CSS just for demonstration:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

This has the drawback that the clearing element tends to take up some space, especially in older versions of IE that had the strange idea that an element always has to be at least one character high. To make the clearing element invisible in all browsers, the elaborate styles that you see in your second example was developed.

Later on there were other variations of this, for example using the `content` style to add the clearing element instead of adding an element in the markup. Some variations of these "clearfix" codes contains CSS hacks, like the `* html` hack in your second example.

The other approach for a "clearfix" is to use a side effect of the `overflow` style. Applying `overflow` (other than `visible`) to an element will make it contain its children, and if you don't specify dimensions for the element it will still get its size from the content and there won't be any actual overflow. Example:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
  <div style="float:left">...</div>
</div>
```

This approach feels a bit like a hack, but it is actually a well documented and intentional effect that is supported by all browsers.